# Customize Xgboost evaluation metric

Tags: machine-learning, python, boosting

I am trying to customize the evaluation metric used for an Xgboost prediction model (Implemented in Python).

And I have an issue:

- I want to consider not only the predicted and the true values (add more parameters like costs...).

Indeed, it's possible with the predicted and true values via the sklearn make_scorer function. But does anyone know about another way to do it in order to consider more parameters?